# Are there studies of Sidon sequences (or sets) which have the further property of all possible sums of their members being different, not just pairs?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

A Sidon sequence (or set) is defined to be a sequence of natural numbers in which all pairwise sums a<sub>i</sub> + a<sub>j</sub> (i ≤ j) are different (for more information, see Wikipedia, for example).

Here is an example of a set that meets the Sidon sequence definition but not the further criterion I've described above:

S = {1,2,5,7} satisfies the definition of a Sidon sequence but if one considers all possible sums of the members of A, certain values appear more than once:

1 + 1 = 2 ("sum" of one member on rhs, i.e. 2)
2 + 5 = 7 ("sum" of one member on rhs, i.e. 7)
5 + 5 = 1 + 2 + 7
7 + 7 = 2 + 5 +7
1 + 7 = 1 + 2 + 5

Does anyone know of any resources (Web, papers, books, etc.) which investigate Sidon sequences for which all possible sums are different? Similarly, are there (well-known) Sidon sequences which can be shown to have this property anyway?

(Without going into detail, this question arose from consideration of the total resistance in an electrical circuit comprising a set of resistors and switches. Actually, for my original electrical circuit problem, I didn't need the Sidon sequence requirement that sums of members added to themselves are included, i.e. when i = j.)

Comment: One simple observation is that, given an integer $b \ge 2$, if we exclude sums with the same addendum appearing $b^k$ times, $k \ge 1$, any $\{1, b, b^2, \ldots b^n\}$ set will work, if I am not wrong.

Comment: From your other posts on this topic, I see how your Sidon set example satisfying my extra constraint is effectively the positional notation system in base-b, which strongly convinces me of its validity; interestingly, for such a Sidon set with cardinality N, say, every possible sum will look like a binary sequence even if in a base greater than base-2, e.g. for the set S = {1, b}, N=2 and all possible sums are 00, 01, 10, and 11 whatever base-b they're written in (b ≥ 2). Many thanks, J.

Answer (score 1):

There are of course "sum free sets" i.e. subsets of integers, say A, such that a + b = c
has no solution in A. This part of mathematics is sometimes called
"Additive Combinatorics". There is quite extensive literature related to this, for example see the book by T.Tao with the same title.
Of course the sequence 3^k has such property and I think this is in a sense a generic example. That is, it looks likely that for any infinite "all sums free" set, say {n_1,n_2,...} there is a constant c > 1 such that n_k >c^k.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and pointers to literature on this topic -- having studied physics rather than maths at university, I never took lectures in the more abstract branches such as number theory, advanced combinatorics, etc. (Much to my regret, and trying to make up for this with some self-study!) Best regards, J.